# JavaScript .closest returning null

Tags: javascript

I have the following simple layout which I am unable to change. I am trying to use JavaScript to get the `extra` element which is closest to the button that was pressed

With help from another question I was able to get the `preventDefault` part working but now I am struggling with `closest`

```
<div class="buttons">
    <div class="button">
        <button class="myButton">Click Me</button>
        <div class="extra">64736</div>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <button class="myButton">Click Me</button>
        <div class="extra">5446</div>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <button class="myButton">Click Me</button>
        <div class="extra">78667</div>
    </div>
</div>

document.querySelector('.myButton').addEventListener('click', myFunction);

function myFunction() {

    event.preventDefault();

    close = this.closest(".extra"); 

    console.log(close)

}
```

But this is giving me `null` when I press the button, where am I going wrong?

Comment: On a different note: you realise you're only adding a click handler to the first button, right? If you want all of them, you need `querySelectorAll(...).forEach(...)`

Comment: Did you [read the specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)?

Comment: closest returns an ancestor. Your `.myButton` elements have no ancestor matching `.extra`.

Comment: closest isn't a jquery only method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

Comment: OP never talked about jQuery. javascript !== jQuery

Answer (score 3):

A combination of `closest` and `querySelector` can be used:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.myButton').forEach(function(button) {
  button.addEventListener('click', myFunction);
});

function myFunction(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();

  var closest = evt.currentTarget.closest(".button").querySelector('.extra');

  console.log(closest)

}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <div class="button">
    <button class="myButton">Click Me</button>
    <div class="extra">64736</div>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <button class="myButton">Click Me</button>
    <div class="extra">5446</div>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <button class="myButton">Click Me</button>
    <div class="extra">78667</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

More info:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Answer (score 0):

.closest traverses up the dom and does not look at sibling or child elements. In the answer by @MaartenDev he is using .closest to step up one level and target the buttons parent div. He then chains queryselector to step back down into the children and select using the .extra class.
Another solution would be to use [.nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) so you do not have to step up and back down. This would only work if your html elements were direct siblings and the item you were trying to target followed the element you were calling nextElementSibling on.

Here is an example of this.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.myButton').forEach(function(button){
  button.addEventListener('click',myFunction);
})
function myFunction() {
  
  event.preventDefault();
  
  var closest = this.nextElementSibling;
  
  console.log(closest);

}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
    <div class="button">
        <button class="myButton">Click Me</button>
        <div class="extra">64736</div>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <button class="myButton">Click Me</button>
        <div class="extra">5446</div>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <button class="myButton">Click Me</button>
        <div class="extra">78667</div>
    </div>
</div>
```